# How to access MPMediaPickerController navigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mpmediapickercontroller

I want to be able to access the `navigationController` of `MPMediaPickerController` so that I can change '`navigationController.tabBarController.selectedIndex`'. However it seems like I cannot access it. In iOS 7, the default tab for a `MPMediaPickerController` is the Playlists tab, but I want to change it to the Songs tab. I know it's possible because I see other apps like Rise Alarm Clock have done this, but I have no clue how they do it.

Here are the `subviews` for `MPMediaPickerController`:

```
<UIWindow: 0x14e812a0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x14e81a30>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x14e81a80>>
   | <UIView: 0x14ed3c10; frame = (0 0; 320 568); layer = <CALayer: 0x14ee8d50>>
   |    | <_UISizeTrackingView: 0x14d45050; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x14d44d70>>
   |    |    | <_UIRemoteView: 0x14d446c0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); transform = [0.5, -0, 0, 0.5, -0, 0]; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayerHost: 0x14d44020>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`MPMediaPickerController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, so you can just use the standard view controller methods to access its navigation controller or bar - `.navigationController` and `tabBarController`.

If you cannot access it via those methods you should assume the class is designed to not let you have access to them. It may well be possibly to get access to the underlying tab-bar by iterating through the various sub-views of the controller, but this is unadvisable.

Comment: Could you provide more info on how to iterate through the subviews to find the tab bar ?

Comment: Just have a recursive for-loop that goes through the subviews of the `MPMediaPickerController`'s view. But bear in mind this is very bad practice, as you shouldn't be messing with system provided controls and they can change their layout and structure from release to release, resulting in your app breaking.

Comment: I did a recursive description to find the subviews, see updated question. Which subview do I access the tab bar from?